# Proof of Polyates Lemma

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers

In Sbiis Saibian's site I came across Polyates Lemma which states that

$$(b \uparrow^k m) \uparrow^k n\ <\ b\uparrow^k (m+n)$$

for all positive integers b,m,n,k with $b\ge 2$ and $k\ge 2$.

He promised to prove this in section $3.3$, but I could not find it there.

Of course, I thought of induction. But should I do it over $m$, over $n$ or
 a double induction ?

The base case is clear, but I did not manage the induction step.

Comment: I arrived at $\large (b\uparrow^k m) \uparrow^{k-1} b\uparrow^k (m+n)$

Comment: But this seems to lead nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detailed a complete proof here: 
https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/home/appendix/c

-- Sbiis Saibian

Comment: While the information at the link _may_ provide an answer to this question, currently [_this_ is not an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259). Consider editing this to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.